# Can audits be skipped?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

When reviewing you sometimes get an item in which you are in doubt whether it is good or not, so you can skip the review and let others who are more qualified judge the item.

Sometimes with an audit I am in doubt as well, what happens if I skip that audit? (So far I never skipped an audit that I know of).

And on a side note: do you gain anything when you complete an audit correctly?

For example, my last failed audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7082610

I was in doubt, and knew it was an audit, but I thought the answer was acceptable. Although maybe not correct, but IMHO answers don't have to be correct to be allowed. Let the OP respond to the answer after which the answer maybe might be edited to a correct one.

I could have skipped the audit (I think), but that doesn't feel right ...

Personally I know I:

- reject more edits, than I accept (maybe reject too many)
- accept more first posts and late answers than I vote to close

My failed audits are usually the ones where I accept a post which the system thinks I should have voted to close.

I try to be honest and fair and not just vote all audits down, just to pass the audit. I don't like to take a way around the system by skipping the audits.

Comment: I skip a very lot of reviews. Nothing bad about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When something is used as an audit, the system has already taken care of it. So the votes you cast in an audit don't make a difference.

Skipping an audit shouldn't be a problem; I skip a lot of audits, especially in the Suggested Edits queue, because I don't want to waste my reviewing slots.

It is certainly better to skip something than to judge it wrongly.

Note that audits aren't always right; most audits are automatically selected from highly upvoted or downvoted posts, but score is not always a good indication of quality. We have the [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) for exactly that reason.

Comment: thanks! I didnt know how the audits were selected, this makes a lot of sense. I will skip more often now :)